# Postgresql base64 encode

Tags: postgresql

I need to convert a db value into base64encode. I tried:

```
 select encode(cast(est_name as text),'base64') from establishments;
```

It showing error

```
[SQL]select encode(string(cast(est_name as text)),'base64') from establishments;

[Err] ERROR:  function string(text) does not exist
LINE 1: select encode(string(cast(est_name as text)),'base64') from ...
                      ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Where I am wrong? please help. thanks in advance

Answer (score 22):

The `encode` function encodes from bytea to text.

```
select encode(est_name::bytea, 'base64') 
from establishments;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-binarystring.html#FUNCTIONS-BINARYSTRING-OTHER

Comment: It showing error:
[SQL]select encode(est_name::bytea, 'base64') from establishments;

[Err] ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type bytea


The actual field type is character_varying(250)

Comment: @Pradeep What is the type of `est_name`? Show sample data

Comment: The field is varchar (250) and sample data below :

Gift Express,
Mozart Musical Instruments,
Ralph Lauren,
Toscana,
Damas,
Atrium Cafe,
Tanagra etc

Comment: @Pradeep Works for me. Is the `etc` the end of the data or it means there is more? Add a few lines of the data to the question.

Comment: I am using 9.2 version

Answer (score 7):

Encode decode examples for string

```
select encode('mystring'::bytea, 'base64');
select convert_from(decode('bXlzdHJpbmc=', 'base64'), 'UTF8');
```

From existing column in table

```
select encode(mycolum::bytea, 'base64') from mytable;
```